# How do I download an image stream returned an axios.post response, from an external Node/Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, export

Alright, so I'm fairly new to Node/Express. I've got an Angular chart, and a React-based Node exporting service.

When you click on a chart's export button, it should create an SVG, pass it along to the export service in an `axios.post` request, convert it to React component, and export the HTML -> PNG via an image stream, in memory, which should be downloaded on the client when we get a successful response back.

I've tried a Blob, a Buffer, hacking an image.src, etc. I can't seem to get it.

The response passes back the raw image string, so all of that works (if that's what I *should* be returning)... but I can't get it to download on the client. After digging, I found out that `res.download` only works with `GET`, but I specifically need a `POST` here to pass the SVG and other random data up to the export server (too large for query params).

I'm not sure if it's just that I'm converting it incorrectly (stream) and I can't parse it correctly on the client, or if I'm missing something key.

Here are some snippets:

**Angular Service**

```
// ...stuff...
exportPNG(chart) {
    const exportServiceURL = 'someUrl.com'
    const svg = chart.toSvg();
    const params = { svg, ...someOtherData};
    const exportUrl = `${exportServiceURL}/exports/image/chart`;
    return axios.post(exportUrl, params).then(res => {
      //... I need to download the response's image somehow, here?
      // res.data looks like "�PNG IHDR�9]�{pHYs��IDATx^�}T[Ǚ�w6�\(-��c[؍�� ')�...
    });
```

**React/Export service:**

```
// ...stuff...
async getChart (req, res) => {
    const deferred = async.defer();
    const filename = 'reportingExport.png';

    // Returns HTML, wrapped around the SVG string.
    const html = this.getChartHtml(req.body); 
    const stream = await this.htmlToImageStream(html, filename);

    stream.on('open', () => this.pipeStream(req, res, stream, filename));
}

async htmlToImageStream(html, tempFilename) {
    const deferred = async.defer();

    webshot(html, tempFilename, { siteType: 'html' }, err => {
        if (err) deferred.error(err);
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(tempFilename);
        // Does cleanup, fs.unlink, not important
        stream.on('end', () => this.imageExportStreamEnd(stream, tempFilename));
        deferred.resolve(stream);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

pipeStream(req, res, stream, filename) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/png');
    //res.attachment(filename); // this didn't work
    res.download(`${path.join(__dirname, '../../../')}${filename}`, filename);
    stream.pipe(res); // Seems to return an actual PNG
}
```